# Follow up about using VBA to send e-mail

Tags: email, vba, excel

This is a follow up to several messages about using VBA to send e-mail.

Most suggestions use either Outlook, CDO, or MAPI:

```
Set appOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 

Set msgOne = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

Set mapi_session = New MSMAPI.MAPISession
```

But apparently Outlook will require me to change our workgroup security settings, and CDO and MAPI will require me to add a DLL or something.

I'm trying to use Excel to organize group assignments at work and I can't modify the other people's computers in any way.

Is there a simpler way to send e-mails from an Excel macro?
All I need is a block of text in the body of the message with no attachments.

I've been plowing through Google, MSDN & StackOverflow all week and I'm stuck on a slow boat to nowhere.

Answer (score 9):

Building up on what Marc mentioned, Here is a **tried and tested** version.

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Sub SendMail()
    Dim objMail As String
    Dim oMailSubj, oMailTo, oMailBody As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    oMailSubj = "YOUR SUBJECT GOES HERE"
    oMailTo = "ABC@ABC.COM"
    oMailBody = "BLAH BLAH!!!!"
    objMail = "mailto:" & oMailTo & "?subject=" & oMailSubj & "&body=" & oMailBody

    ShellExecute 0, vbNullString, objMail, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    Application.SendKeys "%s"

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> > > Thanks for the info. I had already ruled out ShellExecute because it limits the entire parameter string to 250 char and I need about 2000 for the message. But it's looking like SE is the only option that will actually work in my case. – Humanoid1000 7 hours ago

Here is the "Horrible (*I love the way JFC says that!!!*)" way I mentioned below in the comments which works beautifully :) BTW I have only Outlook as my default client so I have tested it with that.

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub SendMail()
    Dim objMail As String
    Dim oMailSubj As String, oMailTo As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objDoc As Object, objSel As Object, objOutlook As Object
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Open the txt file which has the body text and read it in one go
    Open "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\Sample.Txt" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    Sleep 300

    oMailSubj = "YOUR SUBJECT GOES HERE"
    oMailTo = "ABC@ABC.COM"
    objMail = "mailto:" & oMailTo & "?subject=" & oMailSubj

    ShellExecute 0, vbNullString, objMail, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus

    Sleep 300

    Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    '~~> Get a Word.Selection from the open Outlook item
    Set objDoc = objOutlook.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection

    objDoc.Activate

    Sleep 300

    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        objSel.TypeText strData(i)
        objSel.TypeText vbNewLine
    Next i

    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing

    '~~> Uncomment the below to actually send the email
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    'Application.SendKeys "%s"

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

Text File which has the message

[image]

Email just before it is sent

[image]

Comment: If I remember well the mailto protocol as limits on the body lenght. (no more than 512 chars). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I had already ruled out ShellExecute 
because it limits the entire parameter string to 250 char and 
I need about 2000 for the message.  But it's looking like SE 
is the only option that will actually work in my case.

Comment: Siddharth, I believe you have a typo in your code.
The objMail line should have the string "&body=".
(note the ampersand)

Comment: I dug into this a little deeper and found an interesting 
work around for the 250 char limit.  For those of you who 
are using Outlook Express, this guy puts a huge parameter 
string in a file then passes the file name to ShellExecute 
instead of the parameter string.  It's way clever, but only 
works for Outlook Express, and not Outlook because Outlook 
uses a binary file that can't be easily created manually. 

http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/shell/shellexecute.htm

Comment: @Humanoid1000: Yes that was a typo which I have rectified. Regarding your character limit, I have a "HORRIBLE" idea ;) gimme 15 minutes. Will update the post soon.

Comment: That looks like a pretty good work around.   I'll probably 
just stick to 100 char of text with a link to the file that
they need to view.   We're running 2 or 3 versions of Windows, 
Office & Outlook, and I want to minimize troubleshooting.

Here are two possible enhancements:
Add a line to make it happen invisibly:
   objOutlook.Visible = 0  
Copy text direct from Excel:
   objSel.TypeText  Sheets("LogSheet").Cells(RW, 2).Value
   RW = RW + 1
I doubt if either of those will work as written.

It'll take me a few days to try these out (I don't have
Outlook at home).

Answer (score 5):

You can probably use the `Shell` command.

```
Shell("mailto:username@isp.com")
```

If Outlook is your default email program, I think windows will interpret that properly (it does it from the windows RUN dialog, but not sure if from VBA).  Try it out.  I'm not in front of Excel at the moment.

Review the params for "mailto" to see how you can add subject and body to that string.

**CORRECTION:**
That will only generate the email, but won't send it.  Disregard my answer.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, been seeing a lot of you on these Excel questions lately Siddarth. Good work!

Comment: nice shot both of you :) - i've been out from SO for a while but I can see there are still valuable answers (even if I didn't expect less from you :))

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final result:

Turns out, the `SendMail()` worked at home but not at work, but `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` did work at work.

My security settings were not the problem with Outlook, it was a mundane typo.

Either way, there's bunch of good info on this page for anyone else who's lost on this topic.