# Automatically send an Email when the VBA code gives an error

Tags: vba, error-handling, outlook

I am writing a VBA macro which is to be used by others who will not be VBA users. Hence, I would like to embed a system in the code which, when the code throws an error, automatically sends me an email from the outlook account of user of the macro. Would this be possible with VBA? Also, the user would not be having admin access to their account, will this create an issue? Thanks in advance for your help on this!

EDIT - I now know that this is possible and also have a vba code for the same (see below). However, can we eliminate the "Security warning box" that pops up when we try to send the email automatically. Also, I would like to attach the erring file along with the email. It would be great if I get some help on this, Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can send an email when the error occurs. I don't think Admin access should be a problem if the users can open Outlook directly :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for your response. I would require major hints to solve this problem, I would greatly appreciate if you can chip in! Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. **UNTESTED**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '
    '~~> Rest of the Code
    '

    Exit Sub
 Whoa:
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = "abc@abc.com"
        .Subject = "Error Occured - Error Number " & Err.Number
        .Body = Err.Description

        .Display '~~> Change this to .Send for sending the email
    End With

    Set OutApp = Nothing: Set OutMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> Is there a way I can also attach the excel file having the macro? I will edit main question as well to reflect this. – hardikudeshi 5 mins ago

Try this.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTempPath _
Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" _
(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, _
ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '
    '~~> Rest of the Code
    '

    Exit Sub
 Whoa:
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.SaveAs TempPath & "ErroringFile.xls", FileFormat:= _
    xlNormal
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = "abc@abc.com"
        .Subject = "Error Occured - Error Number " & Err.Number
        .Body = Err.Description
        .Attachments.Add TempPath & "ErroringFile.xls"

        .Display '~~> Chnage this to .Send for sending the email
    End With

    Set OutApp = Nothing: Set OutMail = Nothing
End Sub

Function TempPath() As String
    TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
    GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
    TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function
```

Comment: It seems to be working. Thanks a ton! However, this is still a minor annoyance. A message comes "A program is trying to automatically send e-mail on your behalf. Do you want to allow this? If this is unexpected, it may be a virus and you should choose 'No'". Is there a way to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: sorry for progressively increasing the scope of question. Is there a way I can also attach the excel file having the macro? I will edit main question as well to reflect this.

Comment: No there is no way programmatically to stop that. You can explore the option of using `SendKeys` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367841/follow-up-about-using-vba-to-send-e-mail/10368058#10368058) but they are not too reliable.. If you lower the security in your outlook then you will not get that dialog box but then it will be difficult for you to do it for every user...

Comment: seems quite complex, so I guess I would go with the above code for the moment, thanks!

Comment: I am getting an error "Variable not defined" for 'xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled'. Is it because I am using excel 2003?

Comment: Yes. Change .xlsm to .xls and delete the part `, FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` and replace it as shown above. i have updated the post

Comment: No. The code is fine. However, i just realized that the files might need to be zipped in some cases when they are quite large. Any solution? I am sure you have one ;)

Comment: http://www.rondebruin.nl/windowsxpzip.htm Also search Google for "zip files using VBA" You will see plenty of examples :)

Comment: You might consider using CDOSYS to send the email to avoid dialog boxes.  http://www.rondebruin.nl/cdo.htm

Comment: Why not use Environ("temp") instead of the API?

Comment: Is there a way we could handle errors on a complete preject without setting up the  "On Error GoTo Whoa" on every sub ?

Comment: yes it is but the procedures should be connected to the main procedure which has the error handling. @Phoenix

Comment: I had look around a bit that but i havn't found anything on internet. Do you have a link to a thread or maybe a good keyword to find that ? Thanks @SiddharthRout